# what is an example or real world usage of carriage return and form feed in javascript

Tags: javascript, carriage-return

carriage return or \r means it brings cursor to beginning of line.
form feed or \f means it brings cursor to next page

But when I try :

```
console.log("message \r get here \f form feed");
```

I see below output:

```
message get here  form feed
```

I am not able to understand how this output matches with above definitions of \r and \f OR these comes into handy only when taking a print or emails?

I tried logging \r and \f in console but output don't match their definitions.

Comment: CR is mostly a leftover code from the typewriter era. \n would only move the typing head one line down. You needed \r to move the head to column 0. I'd imagine \f was also for a similar purpose

Comment: `console.log()` is pretty liberal at interpreting the input data and doesn't have to follow typewriter standards in the first place.

Comment: It also depends on what environment you run JS in. I'd imagine browser consoles ignore those, while Node.js would print them to stdout and it would be up to your terminal program to interpret them somehow.

Comment: in my console, Mac + Chrome: \n\r. That won't say it'll work on any browser any computer any system (by the way it's ok also on Linux)

Comment: These things: [Teleprinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter). ASCII is a coding that is old enough to have a significant legacy. Not everything you find there still has a practical use today.

Comment: Form feed doesn't have a use case in a pageless environment (or rather an environment with only one very long page).